# generate a big list from a given list by enumeration in prolog

Tags: prolog, combinations, permutation, enumeration

I am trying to generate a big list (2^N elements) from a small given list (N elements). For example,
there is a list [X,Y,Z], in which X, Y or Z could only be 0.1 or 0.9. I will pick 0.1 or 0.9 from X, pick 0.1 or 0.9 from Y and pick 0.1 or 0.9 from Z sequentially, then see X*Y*Z as an element of the new list. So there should be 2^N elements in the new list `[0.001,0.009,0.009,...,0.729]` (`[0.1*0.1*0.1, 0.1*0.1*0.9, 0.1*0.9*0.1, ..., 0.9*0.9*0.9]`). How can I get this new list from the given list? N is a parameter acquired from the given list,

```
trn(List_given,Outlist):-
    length(List_given,N),
    ...
```

I just want to implement like this,

```
?- trn([X,Y],Out).
Out=[0.01,0.09,0.09,0.81].
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm a little confused. Shouldn't it be N^N?

Comment: because X,Y or Z can only be 0.1 or 0.9, just two options, then 2*2*2 (2^N).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To generate the possible combinations of your values:

```
mem(L, E) :- member(E, L).

gen_values(N, Choices, Values) :-
    length(Values, N),
    maplist(mem(Choices), Values).
```

So:

```
| ?- gen_values(3, [0.1, 0.9], L).

L = [0.10000000000000001,0.10000000000000001,0.10000000000000001] ? a

L = [0.10000000000000001,0.10000000000000001,0.90000000000000002]

L = [0.10000000000000001,0.90000000000000002,0.10000000000000001]

L = [0.10000000000000001,0.90000000000000002,0.90000000000000002]

L = [0.90000000000000002,0.10000000000000001,0.10000000000000001]

L = [0.90000000000000002,0.10000000000000001,0.90000000000000002]

L = [0.90000000000000002,0.90000000000000002,0.10000000000000001]

L = [0.90000000000000002,0.90000000000000002,0.90000000000000002]

(1 ms) yes
```

Then you need a list multiplier:

```
prodlist(L, P) :-
    prodlist(L, 1, P).

prodlist([X], A, P) :- P is X * A.
prodlist([X,Y|T], A, P) :-
    A1 is X * A,
    prodlist([Y|T], A1, P).
```

Then you can get all of the results with `findall/3`:

```
trn(List_given, Outlist):-
    length(List_given, N),
    findall(X, (gen_values(N, [0.1, 0.9], Values), prodlist(Values, X)), Outlist).
```

Resulting in:

```
| ?- trn([_,_,_], Out).

Out = [0.0010000000000000002,0.0090000000000000028,0.0090000000000000011,0.081000000000000016,0.0090000000000000011,0.081000000000000016,0.081000000000000016,0.72900000000000009]

yes
| ?-
```

You can use `trn([X,Y,Z], Out)` here, but there's really no point. You could just as well define the predicate with the length: `trn(3, Out)`.

Note, there's some slight floating point precision inaccuracy happening, which yields the long decimals. Also, this method doesn't take advantage of the redundancy in calculations, so it's probably not the most efficient approach. And finally, if `N` (the length of the input list) is large, this will explode.

Comment: Thank you so much for giving such a quick and detailed code to me with a great explanation. It's clear and pretty helpful for me.Thanks again!

Comment: Actually, I just use a small value of N (less than 10), so it's good enough.

Comment: @Wayne, that's good. :) If you could accept this as an answer when StackOverflow allows, I'd be much obliged. :)

Comment: @lurker: accepting is always possible, only upvoting needs rep.

Comment: @false thanks. I wasn't sure about how that worked. I think there's also a time delay before an answer can be accepted.